# Can't start IBM WebSphere MQ client using JavaSE YAJSW

Tags: java, ibm-mq, yajsw, jar-with-dependencies

I'm getting some type of error when starting my JavaSE application as a Windows service, but I'm not sure why. Some IBM jar is dumping a humongous bunch of data, but I can't seem to tell what's wrong:

```
FFDC called in uninitialized Trace module



                                    FDCTitle


Product          :- ProductName
Date/Time        :- Tue Apr 29 10:35:47 CEST 2014
System time      :- 1398760547128
Operating System :- Windows 2003
UserID           :- SYSTEM
Java Vendor      :- Oracle Corporation
Java Version     :- 21.0-b17

Source Class     :- com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.PINLSServices
Source Method    :- getMessage(String,HashMap)
ProbeID          :- XC003002
Thread           :- name=Camel (bkr_message_remover) thread #0 - timer://poller priority=5 group=main ccl=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1a5f230


                                      Data
                                      ----

Data        :- none

                              Version information
                              -------------------

Java Message Service Client
7.5.0.0
p000-L120604
Production

WebSphere MQ classes for Java Message Service
7.5.0.0
p000-L120604
Production

IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
7.5.0.0
p000-L120604
Production



                                  Stack trace
                                  -----------

Stack trace to show the location of the FFST call
   FFST Location  :-  java.lang.Exception
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getCurrentPosition(Trace.java:1916)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.createFFSTString(Trace.java:1855)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffstInternal(Trace.java:1744)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffst(Trace.java:1568)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.PINLSServices.getMessage(PINLSServices.java:144)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.getMessage(NLSServices.java:246)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:217)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:420)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6876)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6254)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6189)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6218)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:456)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:703)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receive(JmsTemplate.java:681)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receive(JmsTemplate.java:672)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsPollingConsumer.receive(JmsPollingConsumer.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ConsumerCache.receive(ConsumerCache.java:112)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultConsumerTemplate.receive(DefaultConsumerTemplate.java:91)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultConsumerTemplate.receiveBody(DefaultConsumerTemplate.java:172)
    at com.hm.online.payment.bkr_message_remover.JmsFetcher.process(JmsFetcher.java:27)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:139)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:64)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)


                            Property Store Contents
                            -----------------------

All currently set properties
   MQJMS_TRACE_DIR                                               :-
   MQJMS_TRACE_LEVEL                                             :-
   awt.toolkit                                                   :-  sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.Channels.DefRecon                              :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQCCSID                                        :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQCLNTCF                                       :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQIPADDRV                                      :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQSSLPOLLTIMEOUT                               :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQ_LCLADDR                                     :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.ClntRcvBuffSize                            :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.ClntSndBuffSize                            :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.Connect_Timeout                            :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.EndPort                                    :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.StrPort                                    :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.libpath                                   :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.connector.JCARuntimeHelper                         :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.jms.ForceUserID                                    :-  false
   com.ibm.mq.jms.replyToStyle                                   :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.jms.tuning.usePersistenceFromMD                    :-  <null>
   com.ibm.mq.localAddress                                       :-
   com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.ffst.suppress               :-  0
   com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.standalone            :-  false
   com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status                :-  OFF
   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.forceAllowClientConnection             :-  false
   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.forceDontUseJmqiWorkerThread  :-  false
   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.forceDontUseSharedHconn       :-  false
   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.forceUseJmqiWorkerThread      :-  false
   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.overrideInheritRRSContext              :-  false
   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.overrideProviderVersion                :-  <null>
   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.xaClientEnabled                        :-  false
   file.encoding                                                 :-  Cp1252
   file.encoding.pkg                                             :-  sun.io
   file.separator                                                :-  \
   java.awt.graphicsenv                                          :-  sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
   java.awt.printerjob                                           :-  sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
   java.class.path                                               :-  C:\yajsw-stable-11.11\wrapperApp.jar;C:\BKRMessageRemover\bkr_message...
   java.class.version                                            :-  51.0
   java.endorsed.dirs                                            :-  C:\BKRMessageRemover\lib\endorsed
   java.ext.dirs                                                 :-  C:\BKRMessageRemover\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
   java.home                                                     :-  C:\BKRMessageRemover
   java.io.tmpdir                                                :-  C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\
   java.library.path                                             :-  C:\BKRMessageRemover\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;...
   java.runtime.name                                             :-  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
   java.runtime.version                                          :-  1.7.0-b147
   java.specification.name                                       :-  Java Platform API Specification
   java.specification.vendor                                     :-  Oracle Corporation
   java.specification.version                                    :-  1.7
   java.vendor                                                   :-  Oracle Corporation
   java.vendor.url                                               :-  http://java.oracle.com/
   java.vendor.url.bug                                           :-  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
   java.version                                                  :-  1.7.0
   java.vm.info                                                  :-  mixed mode
   java.vm.name                                                  :-  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
   java.vm.specification.name                                    :-  Java Virtual Machine Specification
   java.vm.specification.vendor                                  :-  Oracle Corporation
   java.vm.specification.version                                 :-  1.7
   java.vm.vendor                                                :-  Oracle Corporation
   java.vm.version                                               :-  21.0-b17
   jna_tmpdir                                                    :-  C:\yajsw-stable-11.11\bat\..\tmp
   line.separator                                                :-

   os.arch                                                       :-  x86
   os.name                                                       :-  <null>
   os.version                                                    :-  5.2
   path.separator                                                :-  ;
   poll.period                                                   :-  30s
   server                                                        :-  deve
   sun.arch.data.model                                           :-  32
   sun.boot.class.path                                           :-  C:\BKRMessageRemover\lib\resources.jar;C:\BKRMessageRemover\lib\rt.ja...
   sun.boot.library.path                                         :-  C:\BKRMessageRemover\bin
   sun.cpu.endian                                                :-  little
   sun.cpu.isalist                                               :-  pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
   sun.desktop                                                   :-  windows
   sun.io.unicode.encoding                                       :-  UnicodeLittle
   sun.java.command                                              :-  org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain
   sun.java.launcher                                             :-  SUN_STANDARD
   sun.jnu.encoding                                              :-  Cp1252
   sun.management.compiler                                       :-  HotSpot Client Compiler
   sun.os.patch.level                                            :-  Service Pack 2
   user.country                                                  :-  US
   user.dir                                                      :-  C:\BKRMessageRemover
   user.home                                                     :-  C:\Documents and Settings\Default User
   user.language                                                 :-  en
   user.name                                                     :-  SYSTEM
   user.script                                                   :-
   user.timezone                                                 :-  Europe/Berlin
   user.variant                                                  :-
   wrapper.additional.1x                                         :-  -Xrs
   wrapper.config                                                :-  C:\yajsw-stable-11.11\conf\wrapper.conf
   wrapper.console.visible                                       :-  false
   wrapper.key                                                   :-  545431178638744240
   wrapper.port                                                  :-  15003
   wrapper.service                                               :-  true
   wrapper.teeName                                               :-  545431178638744240$1398760542738
   wrapper.tmp.path                                              :-  C:\yajsw-stable-11.11\bat\..\tmp
   wrapper.working.dir                                           :-  C:\BKRMessageRemover
   wrapper_home                                                  :-  C:\yajsw-stable-11.11\bat\/..

                           WorkQueueMananger Contents
                           --------------------------

   Maintain ThreadPool size     :-  false
   Maximum ThreadPool size      :-  -1
   ThreadPool inactive timeout  :-  0
   unavailable -                :-  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002

                               Runtime properties
                               ------------------

   Available processors         :-  1
   Free memory in bytes (now)   :-  7199800
   Max memory in bytes          :-  259522560
   Total memory in bytes (now)  :-  18948096

                           Component Manager Contents
                           --------------------------

Common Services Components:
Messaging Provider Components:
   CMVC             :-  p000-L120604
   Class Name       :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent
   Component Name   :-  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq
   Component Title  :-  IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
   Factory Class    :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory
   Version          :-  7.5.0.0




                         Provider Specific Information
                         -----------------------------

Overview of JMS System
Num. Connections : 0
Num. Sessions    : 0
Num. Consumers   : 0
Num. Producers   : 0

Detailed JMS System Information
Connections      :
Sessions         :
Consumers        :
Producers        :
```

I've packaged my stuff and all dependent jars in a single, fat jar (maven-assembly-plugin/jar-with-dependencies). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrade use of mqjms, jmqi, dhbcore and headers (from 7.5.0.0 to 7.0.1.3).

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me in investigating NPE while connecting to MQ from ServiceMix